# disable autocomplete on galaxy s4

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I have the Galaxy S4. Is there a way to turn off the Autocomplete on the dialpad so that the numbers that I dont have saved in my phone won't pop up?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming from the way the question is written, you may want Fixed Dialing Numbers (FDN).

The Samsung Galaxy S4 can be set so that it may only call certain numbers from a set of specified prefixes. This is useful if you only want to call people on a specific network to save additional charges on inter-network calls. To do the restriction, you may need to follow these procedures.

Phone > Menu > Call Settings > Additional Settings > Fixed Dialing Numbers > Enable FDN
Follow the prompts to supply the rest of the information needed.

If you have FDN already enabled, and the number list is too broad, you can try disabling it, and using dialing presets instead.

Comment: I don't think melissa wants to restrict the numbers she can call. My guess is rather she wants to get rid of the "advertisements" of local shops etc. introduced with KitKat. The new dialer makes a look-up (using Maps AFAIK) for numbers not found in the user's contacts.